# FreeType font path Windows

Tags: c++, c++11, freetype, freetype2

I am struggling with Windows and FreeType2. I am following the tutorial and the following is shown as example code:

```
  FT_Library  library;   /* handle to library     */
  FT_Face     face;      /* handle to face object */


  error = FT_Init_FreeType( &library );
  if ( error ) { ... }

  error = FT_New_Face(library, "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/arial.ttf", 0, &face ); // <-- this does not exist...
  if ( error == FT_Err_Unknown_File_Format )
  {
    ... the font file could be opened and read, but it appears
    ... that its font format is unsupported
  }
  else if ( error )
  {
    ... another error code means that the font file could not
    ... be opened or read, or simply that it is broken...
  }
```

This `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/arial.ttf` just simply does not exist, how can I get the Arial font to work with this.

Comment: Of course it doesn't work - `/usr/` is a POSIX style path, not Windows.

Comment: You'll find it under `c:\windows\fonts\ ` (which incidentally is equally wrong to hard-code: you should obtain the path from the system APIs) unless you have e.g. a Cygwin setup that mirrors them there? I think the answer is just that path is wrong for your platform. Why do you need FreeType? Can't you just use the Windows font APIs on Windows?

Comment: I need the path due to using FreeType in a project (which documentation is scarce). So I'm shooting in the dark at the moment! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It varies from system to system. Check [FOLDERID_Fonts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378457(v=vs.85).aspx).